# Android - call a method when a key is pressed in the onscreen keyboard in android

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I want to execute a java method whenever the user presses a key on the onscreen keyboard, in android. For instance, the user opens up the keyboard and presses "T" (or any other key), the function is then called. If a new key is pressed, the function is called again, etc. etc.

I looked at other similar questions on the site, but none of them seemed to work. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
EditText chatbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatbox);
    chatbox.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

               if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    is_typing();
                   Log.d("Key pressed", "A key was definitely pressed");
                }
        return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with "TextWatcher".Below is the sample code for the same

```
     EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // do the stuff , you need to do 

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```